# Access elements with same indices of several arrays of same size

Tags: python, arrays, select

I have two arrays of same size. In general dtype of these arrays is object (dtype = 'O'). What is the best way to access elements with same indicies from both arrays.

> Possibility 1:

```
remove_indices = [i for i in range(len(array1)) if value in array1]
array1 = np.delete(array1, remove_indices, 0)
array2 = np.delete(array2, remove_indices, 0)
```

> Possibility 2:

```
array3 = np.array([[array1[i], array2[i]] for i in range(len(array1)) 
                   if value not in array1[i]])

array1 = array3[:,0]
array2 = array3[:,1]
```

Note that Possibility 2 is faster. Is there any other solution with similar execution time (or faster)? How could I make Possiblity 2 more readable?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand well your examples, but sticking to `What is the best way to access elements with same indicies from both arrays.` make me think about `zip`. But using numpy why not using transpose ?

Like:

```
>>> array1 = numpy.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> array2 = numpy.array([5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
>>> numpy.array([array1, array2])
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
>>> numpy.array([array1, array2]).T
array([[0, 5],
       [1, 6],
       [2, 7],
       [3, 8],
       [4, 9]])
```